# Right Aligning Button in Nav with CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to layout a navigation area using CSS. I'm trying to make my items look like this:

```
+---------------------+
| header        [add] |
|  item 1             |
|  item 2             |
|                     |
+---------------------+
```

In an attempt to do this, I've defined the following HTML:

```
<nav style="width:100%; background-color:gray;">
  <div style="width:100%;">
    <h5 class="nav-title">header</h5>
    <button class="btn pull-right" style="height:1.2rem;">add</button>
  </div>
  <span class="nav-item">
    <span class="icon icon-home"></span>
    item 1
  </span>
  <span class="nav-item active">
    <span class="icon icon-light-up"></span>
    item 2
  </span>
</nav>
```

My relavant CSS looks like this:

```
.nav-item {
  padding: 2px 10px 2px 25px;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.nav-item:active, .nav-group-item.active {
  background-color: #dcdfe1;
}
.nav-item .icon {
  width: 19px;
  height: 18px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -3px;
  margin-right: 7px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px 2px;
}
```

Unfortunately, when this renders, the "add" button is not aligned properly. While its right-aligned, it appears on the same line as "item 1". I'm trying to figure out how to make the "add" button appear on the same line as the "header". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your h5 tag is taking up 100% of the parents width. Set h5 css to > display: inline-block;

> width:50%

And do the same with your button.
Or float both the h5 and button left and right respectivly
If you use the floats then make sure to add an empty div right below the button that has the css property:

> clear:both;

Otherwise the height of the parent div will be zero.

Sorry if the format is wonky in my reply. This is my first response on the phone app.

Answer (score 0):

Place the button before the header and float it to the right:

```
<nav style="width:100%; background-color:gray;">
  <div style="width:100%;">
    <button class="btn pull-right" style="height:1.2rem;">add</button>
    <h5 class="nav-title">header</h5>
  </div>
  <span class="nav-item">
    <span class="icon icon-home"></span>
    item 1
  </span>
  <span class="nav-item active">
    <span class="icon icon-light-up"></span>
    item 2
  </span>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
button {
    float: right;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Live preview: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ck8z6vyb/1/)